# ¿Cómo quedarme de cada dos filas con una cierta condición de igualdad, solo con una de ellas?

Tags: r

tengo una tabla del siguiente tipo recopilando datos de partidos de fútbol de una cierta temporada.

```
     Venue Result GF GA      oponente_1      oponente_2  xG xGA
39   Home      W  1  0   Athletic Club       Barcelona 0.5 0.9
40   Away      D  1  1   Athletic Club          Getafe 0.3 0.3
41   Home      W  2  0   Athletic Club   Real Sociedad 0.9 0.3
42   Away      D  0  0   Athletic Club        Mallorca 1.2 1.6
43   Home      W  2  0   Athletic Club          Alavés 2.3 0.5
44   Away      D  1  1   Athletic Club         Leganés 1.1 0.4
45   Home      L  0  1   Athletic Club        Valencia 1.1 1.7
46   Away      L  0  1   Athletic Club      Celta Vigo 0.2 1.7
47   Home      D  1  1   Athletic Club      Valladolid 1.2 0.8
48   Away      L  0  2   Athletic Club Atlético Madrid 0.4 1.7
49   Home      W  3  0   Athletic Club        Espanyol 0.4 0.7
50   Away      D  0  0   Athletic Club      Villarreal 0.7 0.8
51   Home      W  2  1   Athletic Club         Levante 2.1 0.8
52   Away      W  2  1   Athletic Club         Osasuna 1.0 1.0
53   Home      W  2  0   Athletic Club         Granada 2.2 0.8
54   Away      L  2  3   Athletic Club           Betis 0.9 1.5
55   Home      D  0  0   Athletic Club           Eibar 0.9 0.2
56   Away      D  0  0   Athletic Club     Real Madrid 0.6 2.3
57   Away      D  1  1   Athletic Club         Sevilla 0.2 1.3
58   Home      D  1  1   Athletic Club      Celta Vigo 3.4 0.6
59   Away      D  1  1   Athletic Club        Espanyol 0.9 0.6
60   Home      L  0  2   Athletic Club          Getafe 0.8 1.5
61   Away      L  1  2   Athletic Club   Real Sociedad 0.3 1.6
62   Home      L  0  1   Athletic Club         Osasuna 0.7 0.4
63   Away      L  1  2   Athletic Club          Alavés 0.8 1.6
64   Home      W  1  0   Athletic Club      Villarreal 2.7 0.8
65   Away      W  4  1   Athletic Club      Valladolid 0.7 1.9
66   Home      D  1  1   Athletic Club Atlético Madrid 0.4 1.4
67   Away      D  2  2   Athletic Club           Eibar 1.3 2.1
68   Home      W  1  0   Athletic Club           Betis 1.4 1.4
69   Away      L  0  1   Athletic Club       Barcelona 0.7 1.7
70   Home      W  3  1   Athletic Club        Mallorca 2.3 1.2
71   Away      W  2  0   Athletic Club        Valencia 0.7 1.3
72   Home      L  0  1   Athletic Club     Real Madrid 0.3 2.1
73   Home      L  1  2   Athletic Club         Sevilla 0.8 1.6
74   Away      W  2  1   Athletic Club         Levante 1.0 1.2
75   Home      L  0  2   Athletic Club         Leganés 0.6 1.6
76   Away      L  0  4   Athletic Club         Granada 0.6 2.2
78   Away      W  1  0 Atlético Madrid         Leganés 1.1 0.4
79   Home      W  3  2 Atlético Madrid           Eibar 1.6 0.6
80   Away      L  0  2 Atlético Madrid   Real Sociedad 1.0 1.3
81   Home      D  0  0 Atlético Madrid      Celta Vigo 1.1 0.4
82   Away      W  2  0 Atlético Madrid        Mallorca 1.0 0.5
83   Home      D  0  0 Atlético Madrid     Real Madrid 0.5 0.4
84   Away      D  0  0 Atlético Madrid      Valladolid 0.9 1.1
85   Home      D  1  1 Atlético Madrid        Valencia 1.7 0.6
86   Home      W  2  0 Atlético Madrid   Athletic Club 1.7 0.4
```

Lo que quiero solucionar es, para cada equipo se tienen en la tabla todos los partidos, de forma que si nos centramos en el Atlético de Madrid y el Athletic Club, podemos ver que vamos a tener 4 filas referentes a partidos en los que se han enfrentado, en lugar de dos , ya que para cada equipo aparecen los datos del partido en el que fue visitante y del partido en el que fue local.

Necesito quedarme tan solo con dos de esas 4 filas, una en la que el Athletic fuera local y otra en la que el local fuese el Atlético de Madrid. No tengo idea de qué funciones usar de R.

Answer (score 1):

Usando `dplyr/tidyverse` parece bastante sencillo:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(Venue == "Home") %>% 
  rename(local = oponente_1, 
         visitante = oponente_2) %>% 
  select(-Venue)
```

---

Básicamente filtramos solo las filas con la condición de "Home" (podríamos elegir "Away" para el caso es lo mismo) y por último renombramos las columnas de oponentes en local y visitante.